# How to get the on-click event for iron-image to show target.id as the image and not placeholder div?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

Whenever I use on-click for an iron-image, the click thinks it's coming from the placeholder div, whether the actual image has loaded or not.

Sample code:

```
<iron-image id="imgFullSize"
                preload 
                on-click="myFunc"
                placeholder$="[[loadingImg]]"
                src$=[[fullSizeImageUrl]]></iron-image>
```

and the function:

```
myFunc: function(e){
console.log(e.target); // div#placeholder.faded-out.style-scope.iron-image
console.log(e.target.id); // "placeholder"
console.dir(e);
}
```

The thing renders like so (when the image is loaded):

```
<iron-image id="myImage" preload="" fade="" placeholder="loading.jpg" src="myimage.jpg">
    <div id="sizedImgDiv" role="img" class="style-scope iron-image" style="background-size: contain; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url("myimage.jpg");"></div>
    <img id="img" class="style-scope iron-image" hidden="" src="myimage.jpg">
    <div id="placeholder" class="faded-out style-scope iron-image" style="background-size: contain; background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url("loading.jpg");"></div>
</iron-image>
```

Comment: You can keep your original function but e.target points to the placeholder, so you can try this: e.target.parentNode.

Comment: Schien yeah I've been using some nasty thing e.target.parentElement._resolvedSrc; I'm thinking there's a better way to do this. Polymer.dom(e) still gives me the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The logical image component is either embedded in this div container or at some point the div container is replaced with an image tag. It helps to use the developer tool of your browser to see the final *rendered* source.

See where the "imgFullSize" node is placed in relation to the placeholder tag. You can attach an event this way:

```
document.getElementById('imgFullSize').onclick=function(){
console.log(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the `<div>` placeholder is invisible on top of the `<img>` (`opacity` set to 0 for the fade transition). As a workaround, you could monitor the [`<iron-image>.loading`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-image/iron-image#property-loading) and [`<iron-image>.loaded`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-image/iron-image#property-loaded) properties to detect when the image has finished loading, at which point you could remove the placeholder, which would allow the `<img>` to become the click-event's target:

```
// <iron-image id="image" ...>

Polymer({
  ...

  observers: ['_removePlaceholder(_imageLoading, _imageLoaded)'],

  _removePlaceholder: function(loading, loaded) {
    if (!loading && loaded) {
      // Use rAF to allow fade transition to complete
      // before removing the node.
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const div = this.$.image.$$('#placeholder');
        div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      placeholder: {
        value: 'data:image/false;base64,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'
      }
    },
    
    observers: ['_removePlaceholder(_imageLoading, _imageLoaded)'],

    /**
     * Waits for image to finish loading, and then removes the
     * placeholder so that the click event targets the <img>
     * instead of the <div> placeholder.
     */
    _removePlaceholder: function(loading, loaded) {
      if (!loading && loaded) {
        // Use rAF to allow fade transition to complete
        // before removing the node.
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          const div = this.$.image.$$('#placeholder');
          console.warn('removing placeholder', div);
          div.parentElement.removeChild(div);
        });
      }
    },
    
    _onClickImage: function(e) {
      const el = Polymer.dom(e).rootTarget;
      console.log('rootTarget', el);
      console.log('e.target', e.target);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-image/iron-image.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-image id="image"
                  preload
                  fade
                  loading="{{_imageLoading}}"
                  loaded="{{_imageLoaded}}"
                  on-click="_onClickImage"
                  src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400"
                  placeholder="[[placeholder]]"></iron-image>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RpJRVY?editors=1010)

This solution might be less "hacky" than using the non-public `_resolvedSrc` property, but it's more complex. You'd have to weigh the pros and cons to determine if it's worth it.